# Return promise from Fetch when posting through Nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch, nodemailer

I want to run code in a `.then()` after a `fetch()` resolves, the issue is that my `.then()` does not run after the `POST` method resolves, it does however if it rejects.

What I am doing is sending a mail through my server using Nodemailer. So I'm not entirely sure what the issue is but perhaps Nodemailer doesn't return a promise to the call or it takes too long and therefore it only runs `.then()` if it rejects. Does anyone know what the issue is and how it can be solved or perhaps if there are alternative ways that I can run some code after the `fetch()` has resolved?

Form submission:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  fetch("http://localhost:4000/send_mail", {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  }).then((res) => {
    //This does not run on resolve
    if (res.ok) 
    { }
  });
}
```

Server:

```
app.post("/send_mail", cors(), async (req, res) => {

  await transport.sendMail({
    from: sender,
    to: receiver,
    subject: "Subject",
    html: ``,
    attachments: [{
      filename: filename,
      content: content
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Your `send_mail` endpoint never responds (or uses the request, from what you've shown...)

Comment: Send a response from your server:
`transport.sendMail({
        // mailoptions
    }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(400).send('Error');
        } else {
            res.status(200).send('Success');
        }
    })`

Comment: @yessir Your approach worked for me! Make this into an answer. Only one issue however, what if the response isn't 200 or isn't 400?

Comment: @random1234 You can use whatever you want as a status in parentheses. Here I use '200' for 'success' and '400' for 'error'. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Comment: @yessir Yes but I was thinking, what if the response is an error but not specifically 400? Just like the docs which you linked to says that successful responses are between 200-299 etc. Will 200 and 400 cover all successes and errors or do I need to use a wider range?

Comment: @random1234 If your server is running and you send a valid request to your existing endpoint, you should return one of the status codes you set. You can set different status codes if you want. For example, if authentication is required for your endpoint and the request came without being authenticated you have to send `401`(you can see from docs): `if (!authenticated) return res.status(401).send("authentication required")`.

Comment: '200' and '400' will cover all successes and errors for the code I shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send a response from your server:

```
transport.sendMail({
    // mailoptions
}, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400).send('Error');
    } else {
        res.status(200).send('Success');
    }
})
```

Comment: Nodemailer has a promise-based interface. [Not passing a `callback` to  `sendMail` will make the `sendMail` function return a Promise](https://nodemailer.com/usage/#sending-mail). As the OP already uses (or at least tries to) Promises. It might be a good idea to show how to correctly do that using Promises.

Comment: Quick question, what is the `data` variable for? Is it not unused and unnecessary?

Comment: Contains the sent email information. Unnecessary for this code. You can check it from here: https://nodemailer.com/transports/sendmail/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your server-side code does not send any response, so the request itself hangs infinitely until the request times out either server-side or client-side. So the `then` will never be called instead an error will happen at some point on the client-side.

Your server-side code should look like this:

```
app.post("/send_mail", cors(), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await transport.sendMail({
      from: sender,
      to: receiver,
      subject: "Subject",
      html: ``,
      attachments: [{
       filename: filename,
       content: content
      }
    })
    res.status(200).send('Success');
  } catch (err) {
    // some kind of error response, you need to decide 
    // which status code is the propper one
    res.status(500).send('Error');
  }
});
```